# How to import/parse fxcop/stylecop generated xml reports in TeamCity

Tags: parsing, teamcity, fxcop, stylecop

Our team's build is run via command. It also generates `fxcop` and `stylecop` report `xml` files.
How to `import/parse` them into `TeamCity`?

There is a `Build feature` `XML report processing` - which one supports `fxcop/stylecop`? Is there a plugin for that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell TeamCity to watch specific file location for FxCop reports. Just write the following service message to stdout (through, for example, echo command from cmd file):

`##teamcity[importData type='FxCop' path='<PATH>']`

where `PATH` is path where you expect report to appear during the build. TeamCity will watch `PATH` when it receives this service message until end of the build.

For more information please refer to [this page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/FxCop) in TeamCity documentation